# Adding UserControl dynamically on User interface

Tags: wpf, xaml, mvvm, grid, itemscontrol

In my WPF application, I need to post n number of my user control in in form of rows and columns. My user control is like

[image: My user control is like]

The number of rows can be n, while number of columns will be either 1 or 2 depending on the view user chooses to use.

Here is the collection that contains my UserControls

```
private Collection<TemplateView> _templates;
public Collection<TemplateView> Templates { get { return _templates; } set { _templates = value; } }
```

And here is the XAML code that I used.

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Templates}">
      <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                  <UniformGrid Columns="{Binding NumColumns}" />
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
       </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
       <ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
           <Style>
                <Setter Property="Grid.Column" Value="{Binding ColumnIndex}" />
                <Setter Property="Grid.Row" Value="{Binding RowIndex}" />
            </Style>
        </ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
        <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
              <DataTemplate>
                   <v:TemplateView Content="{Binding }" />
              </DataTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

v:TemplateView is the UserControl whose n copied needs to be posted in rows/columns.

Here is some of the XAML showing binding of UserControl's controls.

```
 <Label Content="{Binding Title, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
 <Label Content="{Binding Type, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Mode=TwoWay}" />
 <TextBlock><Hyperlink Command="{Binding DetailsViewCommand}">Details</Hyperlink>
        </TextBlock>
 <TextBlock><Hyperlink Command="{Binding AddCommand}">Add</Hyperlink>
```

And here is my UserControl's VIewModel's code

```
  private ICommand _detailsViewCommand;
    public ICommand DetailsViewCommand { get { return _detailsViewCommand ?? (_detailsViewCommand = new RelayCommand(DetailsView)); } }

    public void DetailsView()
    {

    }

    private ICommand _addCommand;
    public ICommand AddCommand { get { return _addCommand ?? (_addCommand = new RelayCommand(Add)); } }

    private void Add()
    {

    }

    private string _layerType;
    public string LayerType
    {
        get { return _layerType; }
        set { _layerType = value; }
    }

    private string _title;
    public string Title
    {
        get { return _title; }
        set { _title = value; }
    }
```

All copies of this UserControl will carry different information in labels and Image. So I need to know in the userControl's ViewModel, which UserControls (or which item in Templates Collection) has been clicked when user presses the Details button.

Above XAML and code does not tell me which item/user control was clicked on Details button click. So how should I accomplish the two tasks?

Comment: You need to use a `DelegateCommand` for that. All interaction / input inside these dynamically generated UI elements has to be done via DataBinding or Commands.

Comment: @HighCore I did use data binding and Commands. When I press the Details button, my viewMOdel's Detail method does get called. But I dont know for which UserControl it was called.

Comment: Post the XAML of the UserControl. You can pass data to the command using the `CommandParameter` property.

Comment: @HighCore just posted the XAML of UserControl.
And since when I click 'Details' button, my properties of ViewModel of UserControl shows 'null' value, so how can i pass anything using CommandParameter? Or what should I pass as CommandParameter?
I believe my posting of label code needs to handle this somehow? What do you suggest?

Comment: I don't understand, what do you mean by "shows null value"?

Comment: @HighCore When I click the Details hyperlink in debug, my properties like Type, Title contains null value in code in Visual Studio's Watch. They should show the Title and Type of the user Control whose Details button was pressed.

Comment: post the ViewModel code.

Comment: Can you modify `TemplateView` and put your `AddCommand` and `DetailsViewCommand` inside it?

Comment: @Steve or else use a `RelativeSource` binding and pass the Data Item as the `CommandParameter`. Still, I'm really confused about the OPs current code.

Comment: @Steve please see the edits I have made to the question. My AddCommand, and DetailsViewCommand are already inside TemplateView's VIewModel

Comment: @HighCore what do you mean by OPs current code?

Comment: Your current code. Im confused by it. I don't see how the Data Items' properties can be null, if you're already seeing that on screen.

Comment: I believe my binding to the UserControl's view model is incorrect. In my case how it should be done? ViewModel of Usercontrol is not getting bind be default unless I write the following code in codebehind of my UserControl 

    `TemplatesViewModel _templateViewModel;
     _templateViewModel = new TemplatesViewModel();
     DataContext = _templateViewModel;`

This binds the viewModel to the view of userControl but display null in properties as I said yesterday.